Reaction of neopentylphenylether with HI
Will any reaction take place when neopentylphenylether is reacted with HI? According to what I have learnt, there shouldn't be any reaction since after protonation of the ether, Sn2 reation cannot take place due to the presence of the bulky group and neither can sn1 due to the formation of a highly unstable carbocation. Rearrangement of the carbocation is something to think about AFTER the carbocation is formed, but in this case the carbocation isn't likely to even form, hence no reaction. Am I Correct?


Can't find any literature on this cleavage but from what I know of neopentyl compounds I think this cleavage will go very slowly if at all. Neopentyl halides are very poor electrophiles

@Waylander So would it be feasible to say that the products will not effectively be formed (poor yield)?

I would phrase it as "unlikely to go in good yield", since there appears to be no record of someone trying it
